# Creating a VB.net Dataset in Visual Studio 2010 from an SDE Geodatabase

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, vb.net, add-in

I am building an ArcMap Addin that contains several Windows Forms with controls that need to be bound to a database.  I am trying to decide whether or not to use a native SQL Server Database or an SDE Geodatabase.

I would like to link the forms to the features on the map, which suggests I should use the geodatabase, but I have not found anyway to bind geodatabase tables and fields to WinForms controls at design-time.

Has anyone successfully created a Dataset (xsd) in Visual Studio from an SDE Geodatabase?

Comment: I tried to do what you are claiming, its quit interesting that.....i came to the conclusion of build some kind of ORM that can conect to the ArcSDE

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to couple a VS Dataset (xsd) and ArcSDE Geodatabase without huge efforts. Although you can data bind .NET controls to your geadatabase attributes which in fact emulates a VS dataset (xsd).

you can download **ArcDatabinding** sample [**C# project**](http://edndoc.esri.com/ArcObjects/9.2/SampleZipsNetDtEng/a6eb84fb-93db-4bc3-82a9-874d8890a8caCSharp.zip) from EDN that does the data binding.

It implements PropertyDescriptor, BindingList and ITypedList of .NET Framework.